# InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am doing a bit of testing to figure out how to go UPSERT on my DB in MySQL.

When I try to run this sample piece of code however it returns this error which I am not able to resolve.

The number of %s markers matches the number of variables.

CODE :

```
data = {'codice_utente' : ['100003710190666-G5'] , 'user_id' :[ '100003710190666'] , 'mail' : ['prova@ciao.com'] }
df= pd.DataFrame(data= data )

query = 'INSERT INTO dw_users(codice_utente, user_id, mail) VALUES ( %s , %s , %s )  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE codice_utente=%s , user_id=%s , mail=%s ;'

val = [df.values.tolist()[0]+df.values.tolist()[0]]
my_sql_cursor.executemany(query, val)
connection.commit()
```

I tried all possible formats of `val` to provide data to the function, I tried the following code and this works correctly :

```
data = {'codice_utente' : \['100003710190666-G5'\] , 'user_id' :\[ '100003710190666'\] , 'mail' : \['prova@ciao.com'\] }
df= pd.DataFrame(data= data )

query = 'INSERT INTO dw_users(codice_utente, user_id, mail) VALUES ( %s , %s , %s ) '
val =df.values.tolist()
my_sql_cursor.executemany(query, val)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Why not use `df.to_sql`? Right now the question is manually executing a query that expects 6 parameters but the dataframe contains only 3 columns.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `... ON UPDATE codice_utente  = VALUES(codice_utente)...`? You don't need six parameters if you do this. See syntax examples in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't use `pd.to_sql ` because I didn't find an effective method to go to UPSERT so I preferred to use a MySQL query directly providing the values from Python . 
The values passed to the query are : 
`  val = [df.values.tolist()[0]+df.values.tolist()[0]] `
  , being the concatenation of df values actually contains six fields (3 repeated 2 times )

Comment: @BillKarwin 

I tried using a query of the type    ```INSERT INTO dw_users(user_code, user_id, mail)
VALUES ( '100003710190666-G5' , '100003710190666' , 'test2' ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
user_code = '100003710190666-G5' ```

but it doesn't update my user_id and mail fields 
(user_code is PK )

Comment: No I mean you would set all three columns, but the point I was trying to make is that you don't have to include repetitions of the values. You can reference them. I wrote `...` to indicate that there is more to type, I was just trying to be brief.

Comment: sorry @BillKarwin, I had misunderstood the question ! 
the one I posted above is an excerpt of a function I made to go Upsert up from a pandas DB to MySQL .... 
the function "autogenerates " the sql code to execute depending on the pandas DB passed to it and its columns . 
use the notation`VALUES(user_code)`    then became impossible .